# Getting Mapping Errors When Attempting to Implement Soft Deletes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am attempting to implement "soft deletes" as described at https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/. Unfortunately I'm not having much success.

All I've done so far is to add lines like these to the OnModelCreating method in MyDbContext.cs, so that any records that are "deleted" won't be retrieved by queries:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .Map(m => m.Requires("Status").HasValue("A"))
    .Ignore(m => m.Status);
```

When my code tries to access the database, this error is thrown:

> The property 'Status' is not a declared property on type
>   'SomeEntity'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid
>   primitive property.

If I remove the `Ignore(m => m.Status)` bit, I get this error instead:

> An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details.

The inner exception is:

> (22,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   22:Condition member 'SomeEntity.Status' with a condition other than
>   'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on
>   SomeEntity.Status or remove it from the mapping.

I don't know what file it is referring to when it says the problem was encountered at "line 22". I'm guessing it is something that is automatically generated somewhere.

I only show the mapping code for one entity below, but I get the same type of error for every entity I try to map for soft deletes.

### MyDbContext.cs

(This is auto-generated via the [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator). It is a partial class, so my changes actually are made in the next file.)

```
public partial class MyDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeEntityConfiguration());
        ...

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

### MyDbContext.Extended.cs

(The code I added as a first step in implementing "soft deletes" is in this file.)

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("Status").HasValue("A"))
            .Ignore(m => m.Status);
        ...
    }
}
```

### ThingService.cs

(Used to access the database. This is when the error is triggered.)

```
pubic class ThingService : IThingService
{
    public IList<Thing> GetThings()
    {
        return _context.Things
            .Include(c => c.ChildPropertyA)
            .Include(c => c.ChildPropertyB)
            .Include(c => c.ChildPropertyC)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm using .Net 4.6 and Entity Framework 6.

I'm out of ideas. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that "Status" isn't declared as a property on your entity. With ignored properties they still need to be declared in the entity, EF just ignores it. The downside to this approach is that someone looking at the entity will still "see" the Status column and could try setting it, it just won't do anything.

It's an interesting technique, but nothing is perfect. Personally I use soft-deletes the "lame" way where isDeleted is managed at the repository level as a central rule and the repository returns IQueryable. This way a repository is a very thin, mockable wrapper for entities that enforces central rules like soft-delete and tenancy / authorization, freeing up the business logic to consume the data as it sees fit. The code is dead simple to follow and it doesn't require any "clever" hacks in the DbContext.  The problem I see with that soft-delete implementation is that quite often you will have roles that can inspect "deleted" records. That DbContext won't allow it so you'd need a completely different DbContext to be able to review a deleted row. With the repository & "lame" way, you can default to non-deleted rows and allow for an override to pull back all or just deleted rows as needed.

I'd recommend using a bit flag / Boolean for the IsDeleted state rather than a character for Status. Data integrity is easier to manage with an Is/Isn't state where a character could potentially be set to anything.

Comment: re: "The error seems to indicate that "Status" isn't declared as a property on your entity."

That's what the error says, but Status *is* a property of the entity. I think the .ignore() bit then sort of hides/removes it, which then confuses... something. And that's where I get stuck.

I might end up having to do the "lame" way in the service, but hopefully someone will be able to figure out the issue before I have to do that.

Thanks for the comment!